# Don't make http call on subsequent button clicks

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a button user can click on that makes an http call to fetch data.

When user click the button the first time, I make http call. If the user clicks the button again, just provide the data that was fetched earlier.

How do I do that without storing it in a local variable explicitly? I have tried few things but none seem to work. It always makes the http request. I have tried to use "shareReplay" and "share" operators.

```
<button (click)=getData()>Click me</button>

getData() {
   source$.pipe(
   switchMap(sourceVal => {
      const source2$ = this.getSource2();
      const source3$ = this.getSource3(); -------- I do not want this call to be made on subsequent button clicks because it's a reference data
      return combineLatest([source2$, source3$])
   }),
   map(([source2Val, source3Val]) => {
      //do some processing
      return 'done'
   })
)
}
```

I am using angular and rxjs.

Comment: Could you maybe show what you've tried?  All you need to do is store the results of the http call somewhere on the first call, and then use them if they're already available on subsequent clicks.

Comment: You can disable the button in the click eventlistener and then enable it at the `.then()` stage of the fetch.

Comment: @Redu Can't disable the button, users are allowed to click the button multiple times

Comment: How are you fetching the data?  If you are using any sort of library, I would first investigate if it has a way to enable caching in the library to return previously cached data instead of making its own requests.  If not, you might have to create your own cache in some persistent, global variable/object...

Comment: look up debouncing and throttling.

Comment: This problem can easily escalate to further problems. I myself, given the correct inftrastructure, would allow them to make multiple requests and then race those asynchronus calls and would display the winner. However since the requests are arriving aynchronusly you cant put them all in a `Promise.race()` all at once. You need an asynchronus queue which would accept your requests asynchronously as they arrive and once any of them resolves would flush the queue. Here is my [AQ library](https://github.com/kedicesur/AQ) but it's not fully mature yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the button or prevent sending multiple requests via a variable.

```
fetching = false;

getData() {
   if(!this.fetching) {
       this.fetching = true;
       this.http.get('url').pipe(shareReplay(1), finalize(() => {
           this.fetching = false;
       }));
   }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, it might be worth mentioning that this is known as "debouncing" the request.